# DbContext SaveChanges

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm relatively new to C# and very new to WPF. I've been trying to wrap my head around the concept of MVVM and I've thrown ADO Entity into the mix now.

The purpose of my sample application is to track CAD items. I'm pulling items out of a database and successfully populating my view; great. I've added the information in manually to test that the views are working as they should be.

I'm now, from my application trying to add a new item through a function which I'm launching from my ICommand. As I understand it, I'm creating a new DBContext object, adding an item to it and saving my changes. Executing "SaveChanges()" successfully tells me that 1 row was updated but when I check, the data isn't there? In addition to this, if, I call SaveChanges() again (within the same debug session) it throws an error to indicate that there's multiple entries. Again, when viewing the data via "Show Table Data" I'm seeing nothing.

```
    public void AddNewItem(object parameter)
    {
        using (var dbq = new DBEntities()) {
            var tempItem = dbq.OutstandingCAD.Create();
            tempItem.Id = 2;
            dbq.OutstandingCAD.Add(tempItem);
            dbq.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

Could someone please look over that small block of code and suggest whether what I'm doing is correct and whether my issue lies somewhere else?

Much appreciated

Comment: When you create an entity from the database, its a connected object.  So calling `Add` tries to put it in again.  Hence the error.  You can remove the `Add` line and just save.

Comment: what database technology are you using? a full SQL server? a SQL express instance? the built in LocalDb?

Comment: @paqogomez Thanks very much, I wasn't aware this was the case; I've removed that line. Unfortunately, SaveChanges() still doesn't insert my object.

Comment: @Claies I created a new Service-based Database (.mdf) which has generated an .edmx file. I'm afraid that's all I know, so my best bet is with "LocalDb"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not with your code but the way you are trying to evaluate your work.

There is a Microsoft article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx) which discusses the situation you are experiencing.  It references Visual Studio 2005, but it is still relevant.

Basically, your database is an `.mdf` file that is stored in your project.  your SQL connection string is something like `AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\data.mdf"`.

> One of the things to know when working with local database files is that they are treated as any other content files. For desktop projects, it means that by default, the database file will be copied to the output folder (aka bin) each time the project is built. After F5, here's what it would look like on disk
>
> ```
> MyProject\Data.mdf
> MyProject\MyApp.vb
> MyProject\Bin\Debug\Data.mdf
> MyProject\Bin\Debug\MyApp.exe
> ```
>
> At design-time, MyProject\Data.mdf is used by the data tools. At run-time, the app will be using the database under the output folder. As a result of the copy, many people have the impression that the app did not save the data to the database file. In fact, this is simply because there are two copies of the data file involved. Same applies when looking at the schema/data through the database explorer. The tools are using the copy in the project, not the one in the bin folder.

Essentially, you have 2 copies of your database, one for design-time, one for run-time.  You are looking at the design-time database and not seeing changes that were made to the run-time database.  However, every time you run the project, the run-time database gets overwritten, so it can appear that your changes disappear.  This is really a debugging feature, to keep you from having hundreds of lines in the database from multiple tests of the same feature.  However, some people prefer this kind of persistence, and would use an external SQL instance instead of a project contained `.mdf`.

Comment: Claies, I had no idea that this kind of behavior was happening behind closed doors. Thanks very much for taking the time to reply and help me get this sorted!

Comment: if this helped you to solve your issue, consider an up vote and/or accepting the answer.